# Ganglia's GPU Nvidia module: do we need to patch the ganglia-webfrontend?

Tags: monitoring, ganglia, nvidia

I am trying to add the GPU Nvidia module in [ganglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglia_(software)) ([`/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/`](https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/gpu/nvidia)).

Do we need to apply the `ganglia_web.patch` patch?

If I do not apply the patch, I don't see any GPU metrics when I go to http://localhost/ganglia/

If I try to apply the patch, I have the following issue:

```
ubuntu@server:/usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend$ sudo patch -p0 < /home/ubuntu/gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/ganglia_web.patch
sudo: unable to resolve host server
patching file host_view.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 17.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 37.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 144.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 153.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 169.
5 out of 5 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file host_view.php.rej
patching file templates/default/host_view.tpl
Hunk #1 FAILED at 80.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 89.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file templates/default/host_view.tpl.rej
ubuntu@server:/usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend$ cd /usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend
```

The [readme](https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/gpu/nvidia) does not mention what to do with the patch file.

The web interface does contain the GPU metric, but all images are 404:

[image]

When I go to a `Grid > [name] > [gpu node]`, I don't see any GPU option:

[image]

On the Ganglia server (i.e., on the server where `gmetad` is running), I ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules.git
sudo cp gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/graph.d/*   /usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend/graph.d/
sudo /etc/init.d/gmetad restart
```

On the Ganglia client (i.e., on the server where `gmond` is running, and where the GPU is located), I ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules.git
sudo pip install nvidia-ml-py
sudo cp gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/python_modules/nvidia.py /usr/lib/ganglia/nvidia.py
sudo cp gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/conf.d/nvidia.pyconf /etc/ganglia/conf.d
sudo /etc/init.d/ganglia-monitor restart
```

I use:

- Ganglia Web Frontend version 3.6.1
- Ganglia Web Backend (gmetad) version 3.6.0
- RRDtool version 1.4.7.
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x64 server

Answer (score 3):

After running into this myself, strangely enough yesterday as well. I asked a developer of the module. He said it should "just work" ... so, after playing a bit I found the following to work:

On web host:

1. cp conf.d/nvidia.pyconf /etc/ganglia/conf.d/
2. cp graph.d/* /usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend/graph.d/
3. Restart gmond

On GPU Node  (Note, this is RHEL/SL/Cent package names and locations):

1. Install pip (python-pip)
2. Run: pip install nvidia-ml-py
3. From source:

   ```
   cp conf.d/nvidia.pyconf /etc/ganglia/conf.d/
   cp python_module/nvidia.py /usr/lib64/ganglia/
   ```
4. Restart gmond

No need to patch the web tree now. So, on the Web interface go to:

```
Grid > [name] > [gpu node]
```

There should be a "gpu metrics" in the listing now. Might want to collapse and look. If there *isn't* for some reason, you can go to the *Grid > [Name]* page, and at the bottom in the Metric drop down, select one of the gpu_* metrics. That *may* kick something once you do that. I had to do that to get one of the nodes to display the 'gpu metrics' section... but another I didn't.

YMMV.

-J

Comment: Thanks, don't you have to do `sudo cp gmond_python_modules/gpu/nvidia/graph.d/*   /usr/share/ganglia-webfrontend/graph.d/` on web host?

Comment: Doh! Yes... I did partial yesterday and more today and got stuff crossed. I'll edit the above to add it in. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did everything you mentioned, the web interface does contain the GPU metric, but all images are 404: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rJaxU.png And idea what could be missing?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I had 404 images as well when looking at the GPU metrics from the footer area. To get the "real" ones, I needed to go into a node listing. So, from the header link thing:  Grid > [Grid Name] > [Node] -- From the node listing was a 'gpu metric' section.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Ahh... also they guy I talked with mentioned nvidia-smi and spawning it. So, maybe for some reason they weren't actually using the nvidia-ml-py module to directly access statistics... Or there's some other interaction I don't know.... I'm not a python programmer, and didn't look through the code to see what it was doing exactly.

Comment: Thanks. When I go to a `Grid > [name] > [gpu node]`, I don't see any GPU option: http://i.stack.imgur.com/80Tnq.png

Comment: Hrmm....  do you get output on a GPU node if you run:  `python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nvidia_smi.py`   --- Replacing for location where the nvidia-ml-py package was installed.

Comment: I get: `username@server:~$ python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages nvidia_smi.py
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'`. Is it supposed to contain a `__main__`?

Comment: Hrmm...  if I remember right, `__main__` is what's defined when the file is ran directly. That file should have a:  `if __name__ == "__main__":` at the end of it. The output of python -v is: 2.7.5  -- on the system I have it running on.

Comment: There is no `__main__`, but if I open a Python interpreter, and do `from pynvml import *; nvmlInit(); print "Driver Version:", nvmlSystemGetDriverVersion() ` it does manage to display the correct Nvidia driver version ( which in my case is `352.63`)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu xenial I found I also needed to add `modpython.conf` to tell ganglia's `modpython.so` to load the `nvidia.py` module:

1. Install pip (python-pip)
2. Run: `sudo pip install nvidia-ml-py`
3. From source:

   ```
   cp conf.d/nvidia.pyconf /etc/ganglia/conf.d/
   cp python_module/nvidia.py /usr/lib/ganglia/python_modules/
   ```
4. If you don't have `/etc/ganglia/conf.d/modpython.conf`

   ```
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/ganglia/conf.d/modpython.conf
   modules {
     module {
       name = "python_module"
       path = "/usr/lib/ganglia/modpython.so"
       params = "/usr/lib/ganglia/python_modules/"
     }
   }
   include ('/etc/ganglia/conf.d/*.pyconf')
   EOF
   ```